# Access the Twitter API + GetDirectMessages + Arduino in Python

Tags: python, api, twitter, feed, arduino

Following a tutorial I was able to get and parse the Twitter stream for my own account and send this information through the serial connection to interact with my Arduino project. However I need to get messages sent directly to me and not my public feed. Below is the code to get the public feed then my attempt at trying to get my direct messages.

How can I achieve this?

```
##Import Libraries

import twitter
import serial
import time

##authenticate yourself with twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='*************', consumer_secret='**************', access_token_key='************', access_token_secret='*************')

##set to your serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1a21', 19200)

## check serial port
def checkokay():
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    line=ser.readline()
    time.sleep(3)

    if line == ' ':
            line=ser.readline()
    print 'here'

## Welcome message
print 'Starting Wooden Wave!'

def driptwit():
    status = []
    x = 0

    status = api.GetUserTimeline('wooden_wave') ##grab latest statuses

    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

    ## check for match and write to serial if match
    if drip[0] == '#high':
        print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block high.'
        ser.write('1')
    elif drip[0] == '#low': ##break if done
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block low.'
    elif drip[0] == '#light': ##break if done
        ser.write('2')
        print 'Tweet Recieved, turn on LED.'
    else:
    ser.write('0')
    print 'Awaiting Tweet'

while 1:
driptwit() ## call driptwit function
time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

Attempt at gaining direct messages:

```
##Import Libraries

import twitter
import serial
import time

##authenticate yourself with twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='***********', consumer_secret='***********', access_token_key='***********', access_token_secret='***********')

##set to your serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1a21', 19200)

## check serial port
def checkokay():
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    line=ser.readline()
    time.sleep(3)

    if line == ' ':
            line=ser.readline()
    print 'here'

## Welcome message
print 'Starting Wooden Wave!'

def driptwit():
status = []
x = 0

status = api.GetDirectMessages() ##grab latest statuses

checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

## check for match and write to serial if match
if drip[0] == '#high':
    print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block high.'
    ser.write('1')
elif drip[0] == '#low': ##break if done
    ser.write('0')
    print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block low.'
elif drip[0] == '#light': ##break if done
    ser.write('2')
    print 'Tweet Recieved, turn on LED.'
else:
    ser.write('0')
    print 'Awaiting Tweet'

while 1:
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
    time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

////   UPDATE //

```
def driptwit():
    status = []
    x = 0

    status = api.GetMentions() ##grab latest statuses
    print [s.text for s in status]
    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

    ## check for match and write to serial if match
    if drip[0] == '#high':
        print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block high.'
        ser.write('1')
    elif drip[0] == '#low': ##break if done
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Tweet Recieved, raise block low.'
    elif drip[0] == '#light': ##break if done
        ser.write('2')
        print 'Tweet Recieved, turn on LED.'
    else:
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Awaiting Tweet'

while 1:
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
    time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a quick glance. Could you please elaborate on how the second program fails?

Comment: the output error that I recieve is: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "woodentwit3.py", line 54, in <module>
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
  File "woodentwit3.py", line 35, in driptwit
    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words
IndexError: list index out of range 
Im not sure if this means that the results returned for direct messages are in a different format to the ones returned for a user timeline. Thank you for having a look

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds like `api.GetDirectMessages()` returned an empty list. Print `len(status)` directly after the API call to verify that. Are you sure there are new direct messages available to read? Have you tried setting a specific date with `api.GetDirectMessages()` using the `since` parameter?

Instead of checking for hash tags in the first token only, check the entire string. In other words test `if '#high' in drip` instead of `if drip[0] == '#high'`.

Comment: I have changed it from direct message to mentions and added a print line, so it shows that i can bring in the tweets but it inst letting me brake them down and is unable to find the #tags.

Comment: I'm not having any trouble reading the mentions. However, can you directly compare the unicode strings returned from the library with 8-bit character strings?

Comment: [u'@wooden_wave #low ;)', u'@wooden_wave testing python #low', u'@wooden_wave #low testing if that worked', u'#high test @wooden_wave', u'@wooden_wave #high move it up high', u'@wooden_wave #on test', u'@wooden_wave #Newcastle', u'@wooden_wave LED', u'@wooden_wave 36']
Awaiting Tweet
 this is the output im getting.

Comment: @liamviney That's the output you should be getting. You are comparing against the first token and the hash tags is the second token in the first string.